# How to make a generic dictionary as function parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

My Case(I get compile error because T undefined):

```
public void f1(Dictionary<string,T> d){


}
```

How Can I solve the problem(I cant pass Object i have to pass original var type)?

(I am using .net 4.5)

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add the type parameter `T`:

```
public void f1<T>(Dictionary<string,T> d){
}
```

If you want the dictionary to contain values of any type then your only option is to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` and cast as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, But it can not be ob.f1<T>(null) or just  ob.f1(null) I need dictionary that have diff type values

Comment: @Yosef - you want one single dictionary to handle several types?

Comment: Then what you need isn't generics. Just use 'object' instead of T, and cast as needed.

Comment: I write in question that to do cast not possible

Comment: @Yosef - What do you know about the values? If you can't cast then your only option is to use reflection, or possibly use `dynamic` instead of `object`.